# Java Json - Distinguish different classes with same attributes

Tags: java, json, serialization

I'm currently facing the following problem:
Imagine I have an abstract Class `A` for filtering specific entities. 
So I have a `PassThroughFilter` extending `A`, which does nothing (NIL-Element). Through a decorator pattern I have an other abstract class `A_Dec`, which holds the property `type`. Further, I have classes `B`and `C` both extending `A_Dec`. They use the `type` for various things, so they are logically different. 
A sample filter then could be: `C(type=XC, decorator=B(type=XB, decorator=A))`

Not I want to create a JSON to save to current filter. Which is easy to do, BUT 
for the JSON:

```
{type=X, decorator={}}
```

where `{}` represents `A`I cannot distinguish between `B` and `C`.

An easy fix would be to create a local variable with the name of the class or something other unique. But is there a *proper* way to handle this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try to use `JsonTypeInfo` and `JsonSubTypes` annotations from `Jackson` library. See: [Jackson polymorphic JSON deserialization of an object with an interface property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485923/java-jackson-polymorphic-json-deserialization-of-an-object-with-an-interface-pr), [What @JsonTypeInfo.ID to choose for property = “type.id” for deserialization, JsonTypeInfo.Id.CUSTOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671806/what-jsontypeinfo-id-to-choose-for-property-type-id-for-deserialization-js)

Comment: Since I'm not using Jackson, but Gson I can't use the annotations. But still thanks!

Comment: If you are looking for a solution for `Gson`, take a look on [How to work around Gson serialization giving different results when using generic wildcards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55222355/how-to-work-around-gson-serialization-giving-different-results-when-using-generi/55227392#55227392) and especially on `TypeAwareListJsonAdapter` class.